# Neo4j is running out of memory / GC errors

Tags: garbage-collection, neo4j, out-of-memory, tinkerpop

part of my bachelor thesis is loading a .nt-file (turtle format) into a neo4j database, after reading into it and looking for possible implementations I found out that an implementation with a SailRepositoryConnection by OpenRDF should work just like I need it to, but I ran into heavy OOM/GC problems. 
Libraries that i use:
- Blueprints 2.5
- OpenRDF Sesame 2.7.8
- Neo4j 2.0.3

The System that I use:
- Fedora 19 64bit
- 4 Gb Ram
- Java version 1.7.0_51

My Code is the following:

```
public void loadFile() throws SailException {
        //load file
        Neo4j2Graph neo4jGraph = new Neo4j2Graph(this.DB_DIRECTORY);
        BatchGraph<TransactionalGraph> neo = new BatchGraph<TransactionalGraph>(neo4jGraph, VertexIDType.NUMBER, 1);

    GraphSail sail = new GraphSail( neo4jGraph );
    sail.initialize();

    SailRepositoryConnection connection;
    try { 
        connection = new SailRepository( sail ).getConnection();

        URL url = f.toURI().toURL(); // getClass().getResource( this.f.getCanonicalPath() );
        // System.out.println( "Loading " + url + ": " );

        connection.add(url, null , RDFFormat.NTRIPLES);

        connection.commit();
        connection.close();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

    // System.out.print( "Done." );

    sail.shutDown();
    neo4jGraph.shutdown();
    neo.shutdown();
}
```

With very small .nt files (like 4800 triple) it works just fine.
But trying to load a .nt file that contains 1.8 million triples the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery$TermWeight.<init>(TermQuery.java:53)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery.createWeight(TermQuery.java:199)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher.createNormalizedWeight(Searcher.java:168)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.createNormalizedWeight(IndexSearcher.java:664)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.Query.weight(Query.java:103)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.Hits.<init>(Hits.java:101)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.search(LuceneIndex.java:427)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:314)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.get(LuceneIndex.java:229)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.AbstractAutoIndexerImpl$IndexWrapper.get(AbstractAutoIndexerImpl.java:176)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j2.Neo4j2Graph.getVertices(Neo4j2Graph.java:369)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.oupls.sail.GraphSail$DataStore.findVertex(GraphSail.java:297)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.oupls.sail.GraphSailConnection.getOrCreateVertex(GraphSailConnection.java:241)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.oupls.sail.GraphSailConnection.addStatementInternal(GraphSailConnection.java:208)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.oupls.sail.GraphSailConnection.addStatementInternal(GraphSailConnection.java:165)
    at org.openrdf.sail.helpers.SailConnectionBase.addStatement(SailConnectionBase.java:471)
    at org.openrdf.repository.sail.SailRepositoryConnection.addWithoutCommit(SailRepositoryConnection.java:281)
    at org.openrdf.repository.base.RepositoryConnectionBase.add(RepositoryConnectionBase.java:469)
    at org.openrdf.repository.util.RDFInserter.handleStatement(RDFInserter.java:207)
    at org.openrdf.rio.ntriples.NTriplesParser.parseTriple(NTriplesParser.java:319)
    at org.openrdf.rio.ntriples.NTriplesParser.parse(NTriplesParser.java:193)
    at org.openrdf.rio.ntriples.NTriplesParser.parse(NTriplesParser.java:132)
    at org.openrdf.repository.util.RDFLoader.loadInputStreamOrReader(RDFLoader.java:325)
[Full GC 963967K->963934K(963968K), 5.8010570 secs]
    at org.openrdf.repository.util.RDFLoader.load(RDFLoader.java:222)
    at org.openrdf.repository.util.RDFLoader.load(RDFLoader.java:180)
    at org.openrdf.repository.base.RepositoryConnectionBase.add(RepositoryConnectionBase.java:253)
    at src4neo2graph.QnL2.loadFile(QnL2.java:181)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

I also tried running it with 4Gb on another System but the same errors occurred.
So I tried using some commands for the garbage collection: (not specifically in that order but I tried them all at sometime)

Xms2G -Xmx2G -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=95

But that didn't help either.

I've searched around a lot and this seems to be the implementation everyone is using for loading a .nt File into a Neo4j DB and just like I wrote it works just fine with a small number of triples. 
So basically: Is there something wrong with my implementation?
Are there better ones?
What can I do (besides buying more RAM (like I said I tested with more on another system)) to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the number you set on the batch-graph is the commit size, and you have to call commit after each connection you add. The batch-graph will make sure only each n-th commit is actually a real one. Choose a working number betwee 10k and 100k.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to actually break your file into chunks; just count the statements as they are added and commit() after each nth statement.  There is a convenience class, [SailLoader](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/blueprints/2.5.0/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/oupls/sail/SailLoader.html) ([source](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/master/blueprints-graph-sail/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/oupls/sail/SailLoader.java)), in blueprints-graph-sail which does this for you, e.g.

```
public void loadFile() throws Exception {
    File f = new File("/tmp/sp2bench-1000000.nt.gz");

    Neo4j2Graph neo4jGraph = new Neo4j2Graph(this.DB_DIRECTORY);
    try {
        GraphSail sail = new GraphSail(neo4jGraph);
        sail.initialize();

        try {
            SailLoader loader = new SailLoader(sail);
            loader.setBufferSize(1000);  // this is the default
            loader.setVerbose(true);
            loader.load(f);
        } finally {
            sail.shutDown();
        }
    } finally {
        neo4jGraph.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like a good idea. Thanks a lot! let me try this. :)

Comment: First things first: This implementation works, thank you very much. Secondly: Although it works, the performance is actually horrible (almost 1 hour for 1,8 million triples). Do you have suggestions how to improve it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure how tinkerpop internally works, but I guess everything happens in a single transaction. In Neo4j a transaction is first built up in memory and upon finishing the tx, it's persisted and memory used is freed upon next gc. If you have large transactions, you need a suitable amount of RAM.

If there's no easy way to control transaction sizes within tinkerpop, consider splitting your input file into smaller chunks and import them one-by-one and make sure to call `.commit()` after each chuck.

Comment: I have the same problem, couple of questions,

I'm not sure how internally neo4j stores data when it's working as triple store. Is it subject-becomes->node, predicate-becomes->edge, object-becomes->node ?

As you suggested, If I divide my file into chunks and store them, would it work? as it might need to read the data already committed..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure out the solution? I have the same problem. Did you divide your files in chunks and loaded them? or anything else? If you divide your files in chunks, does your queries work as they were to?

To answer your question,

If you're not planning to use Neo4j as pure triple store. Here's an alternative to load your turtle file really fast and create a graph which can be queried using cypher.

http://michaelbloggs.blogspot.de/2013/05/importing-ttl-turtle-ontologies-in-neo4j.html

Hope it helps!